# How do I use mb_substr to fetch data?

Tags: php, mysql

I can use `mb_substr` in PHP and get part of string,my problem is I want to use this function in MySQL and get part of field data, I don't want to use `foreach` to get part of that.

I want to use this function in this below code.

`subject` is 500 char and I want to get 150 char from that and my database is `UTF-8` and my storage engine is MyISAM.

```
        $allContents = $db->loadAssoc( $db->setQuery("SELECT id , subject FROM contents ;") );
        if ( $allContents ){
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = $allContents; 
        }
        else{
            $data['success'] = false;
        }
```

I don't like to use this method:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ( $allContents as $value )
{
   $topic['id']      = $value['id'];
   $topic['subject'] = mb_substr($value['subject'],0,150,'UTF-8').' ... ';
   $arr = $topic ;
}
```

Can I use `substr` in MySQL like this code?

Comment: [**MySQL Function substring**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL function for doing this would be [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Modify your query to:

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING(subject, 1, 150) FROM contents;
```

But since you're starting from the first character, you could use [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
SELECT id, LEFT(subject, 150) FROM contents;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query=mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");                   
                $sort_content=strlen($row['sort_content']);             
                if($sort_content>260) 
                {
                    $sort = mb_substr($row['sort_content'],0,260, "utf-8"). '...';
                }
                elseif($sort_content<250) 
                {
                    $sort = mb_substr($row['sort_content'],0,250, "utf-8"). '';
                }
```

This might help